# Do corresponding areas in the two hemispheres arise from the same stem cells?

Tags: neuroscience, neuroanatomy

After having asked this [question about the connectivity between clonal cortical neurons](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/66684/connectivity-between-clonal-cortical-neurons), I'd like to know:

> Do corresponding areas in the two hemispheres arise mainly from the same stem
>   cells, such that these areas connect to each other more strongly than to others?

Comment: I answered this question, but I strongly advise you to do more research before asking some of the questions you are posing here. Ask yourself questions and look for answers like "where are the stem cells that give rise to neocortex located" and you will easily answer these questions. I think you are having a tendency to find one piece of information and try to connect it to too many other things without reading intervening information.

Comment: I'll try to take your advice.

Answer (score 1):

No, they don't. The stem cells of each cortical hemisphere are located far from each other, in the subplate below the developing cortex.